# Draw video to canvas on Chrome (Android)

Tags: android, google-chrome, video, canvas, frame

I try to copy video frame to my canvas. I'm using Chrome (v46) on Android tablette (v4.4.4).

The first frame is well drawn but the other are not.

JS :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {

            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var video = document.getElementById('video');

            video.addEventListener('timeupdate',function(){
               ctx.drawImage(video,0,0);
            },false);

    },false);
```

Html

```
<video id="video" autoplay controls muted preload>
    <source src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to look at:

- I'm not sure how you have set up the canvas in your HTML, but one obvious possible problem is with scaling - i.e. if the canvas size is a different size then the video the the scaling may reduce quality.
- The 'time update' callback may not be as regular as you need - most examples of writing video to canvas I have seen set an explicit timer. I'm not sure why this would affect quality but it may be worth playing with.
- The particular video you are using has a simple first frame as it is mostly text, which again may be affecting the look of the playback